# Is router infected?

Tags: networking, router

We have been using Linksys WRT54GL as WIFI access point for couple of years. This morning I discovered that our WIFI network doesn't exist anymore. Instead there was network named "linksys" which had no password.
I unplugged the router from power source and plugged it back, but nothing changed, even holding of reset button. His network address also changed and when I found it, I could login but home page looked like this:

[image: Router home page]

Only buttons that I have are "Save settings" and "Cancel changes". On clicking any of it middle of the page becomes white and vertical scroll bar appear, but this disappears after a second.

Could router be infected with some kind of malware or could this be hardware problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I connected to the router trough telnet and made hard reset. This helped because I could open the homepage and reconfigure router to the old settings. Still I don't know what the problem is, but now at least is fixed.

How to connect to router trough telnet:
You can use program like Putty: http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html

Where you select telnet connection, enter device IP and click open. After that if everything is ok, you will be asked to enter username and password. If they are correct you will get to the router menu, where you can change it settings.

Comment: Might briefly explain how you telnet into your router most people with this problem don't know how to do that.

Comment: @Ramhound Done. Is is understandable?

Answer (score -1):

i used to have a similar problem with those cheapo linksys routers. u need to find a way to **hard-reset** it and set it up freshly. at least thats what i did in this situation and got it to work.

there must be a **pinpointsized button on the back of the router**, try pressing it with a pen for about 30 seconds...

Comment: Like I said, I already tried holding the reset button, but it didn't help.

Comment: make sure u **pressed it long enough, 30 seconds.** if a hard-reset wont help, your device is broken imo.

Comment: Telnet hard-reset helped.

Comment: Also, the WRT54G **L** does not count as a cheap linksyst router.  WRT54G 1 till 3 might have been, but at some point Linksys/Cisco decided to half the RAM. The L version was kept with full RAM and compatability with 3rd party opering systems. It is one of the most solid classic performers in its category.